# Prove or contradict: Between each two solutions of $\arctan x = \sin x$ exists a solution for $1-\cos x = x^2 \cos x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Prove or contradict: Between each two solutions of $\arctan x = \sin x$ exists a solution for $1-\cos x = x^2 \cos x$

I have this question in a sample exam and I don't even know what would be a good way to approach this. I though about finding the ranges where the two difference functions have different slopes or something, but I'm not quite sure..

Comment: I don't know if you noticed it, or if it is even useful, but you can rearrange the  second equation to get $\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\cos(x)$, and $\arctan'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: It's also useful here to note that $x=0$ is a solution for both equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prove it apply the Standard version of Rolle's theorem for $f\left( x \right)=\arctan \left( x \right)-\sin \left( x \right)$. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem)

Comment: Cool together with the hint from @Botond (which I didn't notice on my own) this is quite simple :)

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

we have ;

$1-\cos x = x^2 \cos x \implies \cos(x) = \frac1{x^2+1}$

integrate both sides ,

$\int\cos(x) \,dx = \int\frac1{x^2+1}\,dx$

$\sin(x) = \arctan(x) $  $\quad $

Note : i'm ignoring the constant ,because since $0$ is a solution the constants are equal and can be cancelled.

now $g(x) = \arctan(x)-\sin(x)=0$

Apply [Rolles theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem),

since at roots the values are equal ie $0$, rolles theorem is applicable and proves that between each zeros of $\arctan(x)=\sin(x)$ there exists a root of $1-\cos(x) =x^2\cos(x)$

Comment: Nice, I don't think the integration part of the proof is needed since it just follows from applying rolles theorem, doesn't it?

Comment: It isnt necessary, but i thought that point would show the connection between the two givens.